Excel Ribbon comboBox: set paper size for multiple sheets
This code allows you to select between three sheets in a workbook:
Excel Ribbon comboBox: always display current selection
I'm trying to adapt this to use the comboBox to select from three page sizes.
The Callback works. But I can't figure out the corresponding SaveSetting in Workbook_SheetActivate event to have the comboBox work on multiple sheets and always show the active sheets' page size.
Thanks!
'--XML
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="LoadRibbon">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="Tabv3.1" label="TOOLS" insertAfterMso="TabHome">                                             
                <group id="GroupDemo2" 
                label="SelectPapersize"
                imageMso="AddInManager">
                    <comboBox id="ComboBox001"
                    label="comboBox001"
                    getText="ComboBox001_GetText"
                    onChange="ComboBox001_OnChange">
                        <item id="Item_A3"
                        label="A3"/>
                        <item id="Item_A4"
                        label="A4"/>
                        <item id="Item_A5"
                        label="A5"/>
                    </comboBox>
                </group>   
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>

'--Callback VBA in Module "RibbonCallbacks"
Option Explicit
Public RibUI As IRibbonUI
Public Const myApp As String = "RibbApp", mySett As String = "Settings", myVal As String = "Value"

Sub LoadRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set RibUI = Ribbon
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
End Sub

'Callback for ComboBox001 onChange
Sub ComboBox001_OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, id As String)
    Select Case id
        Case "A3"
'            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
             ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA3
        Case "A4"
'            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        Case "A5"
'            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Select
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA5
    End Select
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
    SaveSetting myApp, mySett, myVal, id
End Sub

'Callback for ComboBox001 getText
Sub ComboBox001_getText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
  Dim comboVal As String
    comboVal = GetSetting(myApp, mySett, myVal, "No Value") 'read it from Registry
    If comboVal <> "No Value" Then
      returnedVal = comboVal
    End If
End Sub

'--VBA in "ThisWorkbook"
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim idx As String
    Select Case PaperSize
    Case "xlPaperA3"
        idx = "A3"
    Case "xlPaperA4"
        idx = "A4"
    Case "xlPaperA5"
        idx = "A5"
    End Select
    SaveSetting myApp, mySett, myVal, idx
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
End Sub


Instead of using GetSetting why not read the paper size from the ActiveSheet?

Sounds good, but I got no clue how I would do that.

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize ?


Don't need to use SaveSetting/GetSetting.


' -- Stardard module

Option Explicit
Public RibUI As IRibbonUI

Sub LoadRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set RibUI = Ribbon
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
End Sub

'Callback for ComboBox001 onChange
Sub ComboBox001_OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, id As String)
    Dim iSize As Long
    Select Case id
        Case "A3"
             iSize = xlPaperA3
        Case "A4"
            iSize = xlPaperA4
        Case "A5"
            iSize = xlPaperA5
    End Select
    If iSize > 0 Then _
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = iSize
End Sub

'Callback for ComboBox001 getText
Sub ComboBox001_getText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = GetPageSize
End Sub

Function GetPageSize() As String
        Select Case ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize
        Case xlPaperA3
            GetPageSize = "A3"
        Case xlPaperA4
            GetPageSize = "A4"
        Case xlPaperA5
            GetPageSize = "A5"
        End Select
End Function


' -- ThisWorkbook

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
End Sub

